# How to create county level chloropeth maps wih plotly

Tags: plotly

Hello i have this code which produces chloropeth map in state level with plotly but i want to produce exactly the same map in counties level. I tried to change the locationmode = 'USA-states' to locationmode = 'USA-counties' but it does not work. Any ideas? (emergency)

```
library(plotly)
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv")
df$hover <- with(df, paste(state, '<br>', "Beef", beef, "Dairy", dairy, "<br>",
                           "Fruits", total.fruits, "Veggies", total.veggies,
                           "<br>", "Wheat", wheat, "Corn", corn))
# give state boundaries a white border
l <- list(color = toRGB("white"), width = 2)
# specify some map projection/options
g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showlakes = TRUE,
  lakecolor = toRGB('white')
)

p <- plot_geo(df, locationmode = 'USA-states') %>%
  add_trace(
    z = ~total.exports, text = ~hover, locations = ~code,
    color = ~total.exports, colors = 'Purples'
  ) %>%
  colorbar(title = "Millions USD") %>%
  layout(
    title = '2011 US Agriculture Exports by State<br>(Hover for breakdown)',
    geo = g
  )
```

Comment: Have you seen https://plot.ly/r/county-level-choropleth/ ?

Comment: I did but i want exactly the same map result as this that i posted.